# JBoss 7.1.1.Final Deployment Error: JandexAnnotationProvider is not an instance of AnnotationProvider

Tags: deployment, jsf-2, jboss, jboss7.x

I'm working on migrating a web application to JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final. The structure of this application is as follows:

```
app.ear
|--- \lib
|       |-- jsf-api-2.0.2.jar, jsf-impl-2.0.2.jar, jsp-api-2.1.jar, jstl-1.2.jar    
|
|--- \META-INF
|--- \web.war
|       |-- \WEB-INF
|       |       |-- web.xml
|       |
|
|--- \ejbs.jar
```

As we can see, this application uses the jsf implementation Mojarra 2.0.2 (FCS b10). The files jsf-impl-2.0.2.jar and jsf-api-2.0.2.jar are in the \ lib at the root of the EAR.

Within the web.xml, I added the parameter, which tells the server that the implementation being used is the one bundled with the application:

*--web.xml:*

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.jboss.jbossfaces.WAR_BUNDLES_JSF_IMPL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Moreover, added the file *jboss-deployment-structure.xml*:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">

<ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>

<deployment>
    <exclusions>
        <!-- Exclude container version of hibernate. By default its version 4, 
            we want bundled version 3 loaded -->
        <module name="org.hibernate" slot="main" />
        <module name="org.hibernate.validator" slot="main" />
        <module name="javax.faces.api" slot="main" />
        <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" slot="main" />
        <module name="javax.faces.api" slot="1.2" />
        <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" slot="1.2" />
    </exclusions>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Add dependencies, since in 'pom.xml' we exclude transitive dependencies 
            from reactor, we need to add following modules, to make application work 
            properly -->
        <!-- NOTE: module name does not always correspond to maven artifact ID -->
        <!-- Add dependency on commons.logging -->
        <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
        <!-- Add dependency on commons.collections -->
        <module name="org.apache.commons.collections" />
        <module name="org.apache.commons.lang" />
        <!-- Add dependency on log4j -->
        <module name="org.apache.log4j" export="true"/>
        <!-- Add dependency on dom4j -->
        <module name="org.dom4j" />
        <!-- Add dependency on slf4j -->
        <module name="org.slf4j" />
        <!-- Add dependency on antlr -->
        <module name="org.antlr" />
        <!-- Add dependency on asm -->
        <module name="asm.asm" />
        <!-- Add dependency on javassist -->
        <module name="org.javassist" />
        <module name="org.hibernate" slot="3" />
        <module name="org.hibernate.validator" slot="3" />
    </dependencies>

</deployment>
```

When trying to deploy this application, the server throws the following exception:

```
   17:39:00,826 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (MSC service thread 1-8) JSF1051: Service entry 'org.jboss.as.web.deployment.jsf.JsfInjectionProvider' does not extend DiscoverableInjectionProvider.  Entry will be ignored.17:39:00,828 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (MSC service thread 1-8) JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy annotations present.  ManagedBeans methods marked with these annotations will have said annotations processed.
17:39:00,903 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-8) Unsanitized stacktrace from failed start...: javax.faces.FacesException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.faces.FacesException: Class org.jboss.as.web.deployment.jsf.JandexAnnotationProvider is not an instance of com.sun.faces.spi.AnnotationProvider
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getAnnotatedClasses(ConfigManager.java:411) [jsf-impl-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2-FCS]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.processAnnotations(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:328) [jsf-impl-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2-FCS]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor.process(ApplicationConfigProcessor.java:334) [jsf-impl-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2-FCS]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:114) [jsf-impl-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2-FCS]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.LifecycleConfigProcessor.process(LifecycleConfigProcessor.java:116) [jsf-impl-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2-FCS]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:114) [jsf-impl-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2-FCS]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:223) [jsf-impl-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2-FCS]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:335) [jsf-impl-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2-FCS]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:223) [jsf-impl-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2-FCS]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885) [rt.jar:1.6.0_07]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907) [rt.jar:1.6.0_07]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [rt.jar:1.6.0_07]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.faces.FacesException: Class org.jboss.as.web.deployment.jsf.JandexAnnotationProvider is not an instance of com.sun.faces.spi.AnnotationProvider
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:222) [rt.jar:1.6.0_07]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83) [rt.jar:1.6.0_07]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getAnnotatedClasses(ConfigManager.java:407) [jsf-impl-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2-FCS]
    ... 16 more
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: Class org.jboss.as.web.deployment.jsf.JandexAnnotationProvider is not an instance of com.sun.faces.spi.AnnotationProvider
    at com.sun.faces.spi.AnnotationProviderFactory.createAnnotationProvider(AnnotationProviderFactory.java:74) [jsf-impl-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2-FCS]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$AnnotationScanTask.call(ConfigManager.java:764) [jsf-impl-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2-FCS]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$AnnotationScanTask.call(ConfigManager.java:736) [jsf-impl-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2-FCS]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303) [rt.jar:1.6.0_07]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) [rt.jar:1.6.0_07]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:329) [jsf-impl-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2-FCS]
    ... 9 more

17:39:00,931 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/war]] (MSC service thread 1-8) Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! Class org.jboss.as.web.deployment.jsf.JandexAnnotationProvider is not an instance of com.sun.faces.spi.AnnotationProvider
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:354) [jsf-impl-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2-FCS]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:223) [jsf-impl-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2-FCS]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885) [rt.jar:1.6.0_07]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907) [rt.jar:1.6.0_07]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [rt.jar:1.6.0_07]
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: Class org.jboss.as.web.deployment.jsf.JandexAnnotationProvider is not an instance of com.sun.faces.spi.AnnotationProvider
    at com.sun.faces.spi.AnnotationProviderFactory.createAnnotationProvider(AnnotationProviderFactory.java:74) [jsf-impl-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2-FCS]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$AnnotationScanTask.call(ConfigManager.java:764) [jsf-impl-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2-FCS]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$AnnotationScanTask.call(ConfigManager.java:736) [jsf-impl-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2-FCS]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303) [rt.jar:1.6.0_07]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) [rt.jar:1.6.0_07]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:329) [jsf-impl-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2-FCS]
    ... 9 more

17:39:00,948 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-8) Error listenerStart
17:39:00,949 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-8) Context [/war] startup failed due to previous errors
17:39:00,952 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-8) Unexpected exception when attempting to tear down the Mojarra runtime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:804) [jsf-api-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2-FCS]
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:306) [jsf-api-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2-FCS]
    at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.getApplication(InitFacesContext.java:104) [jsf-impl-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2-FCS]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextDestroyed(ConfigureListener.java:309) [jsf-impl-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2-FCS]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:3489) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:3999) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3917) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885) [rt.jar:1.6.0_07]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907) [rt.jar:1.6.0_07]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [rt.jar:1.6.0_07]

17:39:00,968 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./war: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./war: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:95)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885) [rt.jar:1.6.0_07]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907) [rt.jar:1.6.0_07]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [rt.jar:1.6.0_07]
```

I made a lot o research, but didnt resolve this problem. Someone knows a way out?

Comment: I don't think you can use your own JSF libraries like that. See https://community.jboss.org/wiki/DesignOfAS7Multi-JSFFeature for more details. Also excluding hibernate is probably not a good idea either if you want to use container managed JPA.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins Accordingly with [this link](https://community.jboss.org/message/622369) we can deploy JSF libs inside ear/lib. Of course, we have to be sure that JBoss AS embedded libs will be disabled. BTW, I have excluded hibernate libraries because this app use version 3.5.6.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to exclude the server's JSF implementation by adding a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` to your procject.

```xml
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <!-- Exclusions allow you to prevent the server from automatically adding some dependencies -->
        <exclusions>
            <module name="javax.faces.api" />
        </exclusions>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="javax.el.api" export="true"/>
            <module name="javax.servlet.api" export="true"/>
            <module name="javax.servlet.jsp.api" export="true"/>
            <module name="javax.servlet.jstl.api" export="true"/>
            <module name="javax.validation.api" export="true"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

With regards to Hibernate, you shouldn't need to include Hibernate in your application. You can tell the server to [use Hibernate 3.5](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/JPA+Reference+Guide#JPAReferenceGuide-PackagingtheHibernate3.5orgreater3.xJPApersistenceproviderwithyourapplication).

Comment: You are right about Hibernate. I configured it on persistence.xml. About JSF, the application is deployed without error, but com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException is threw. I'm no lucky till now :(

Comment: Is there a reason the version of JSF bundled with the server won't work? I know it was forked to fix errors found in the default implementation.